# Error filling print... Infinite loop creating new page

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I get this error when trying to preview the report.

```
Error filling print... Infinite loop creating new page. 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Infinite loop creating new page. 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1903)  
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1961) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillGroupHeaderReprint(JRVerticalFiller.java:704)  
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillGroupHeadersReprint(JRVerticalFiller.java:672)      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1944)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBreak(JRVerticalFiller.java:1961)  
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:747) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:281)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:144) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:822)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:61) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891) 
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572) 
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...
```

Is there an option I have to check or something to make this work?

Comment: Do you have any sub-reports ?

Comment: yes, i have a subreport but this error actually comes when i preview the subreport separately, not the whole report.

Comment: Can you please check the layout of the bands in your subreport? I strongly doubt  it is a layout issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved the problem by eliminating a subreport with the help of adding a detail band. The subreport was in a group header, not in the page header, however. For other people with a similar problem I would suggest a similar approach.

Comment: I change `header band` to `detail band` and problem disappear (stretching works correctly also).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, I increase the vertical size of the report.now the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to write groovy on Print When Expression that `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals(1)` on column header property.

This happened when you drop sub report in detail section so the column header in jasper repeat twice.

So you have to tell column header to not repeat again with sub report.